# how to create a test solar index and then delete the same index from linux using curl

Tags: hadoop, indexing, solr

I need help with solar, i know how to create a solr index but not sure how to delete the same index.
Any reference or help to create a test index and then delete the same index will be helpful.
I checked online but could not find anything that will delete a file that has been added to index.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you'll want to use these [CoreAdmin API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API) controls. If you are interested in deleting an entire test Solr core, not leaving any files around to collect over time, you'll probably want to set the `deleteInstanceDir=true` when you send the unload command.

Or, if I've misunderstood and you're just looking to delete your test files from the index while leaving the index around, this command will empty the index:

```
curl 'http://hostname/solr/core0/update?commit=true' -H "Content-Type: text/xml" \
                         --data-binary '<delete><query>id:*</query></delete>'
```

If you only want to delete a particular record or set of records, you will need to adjust the `<query>id:*</query>` element to apply a query that correctly targets the record(s) you actually want to delete.

Comment: Hi, I did not get a clear picture i have created a index using below:  solrctl --zk 'server:port/solr' --solr 'http://server:8983/solr/' instancedir --generate /home/userid/test1
solrctl --zk 'server:port/solr' --solr 'http://server:8983/solr/' instancedir --create sample_test /home/userid/test1
solrctl --zk 'server:port/solr' --solr 'http://server:8983/solr/' collection --create sample_test -s 1 -r 1                           Can you help me as what should i submit to see the data in index and what exactly should i post in curl to delete whatever i have created using the above commands